# Text Editors on Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, java

Please suggest a text editor for writing my java programs. 
It should be similar to Notepad++. Should have: syntax highlighting, tabs, be colorful, and other advanced features leading to ease in writing programs.
Also, it should be in Ubuntu Software Center as I am not able to download text editors from chrome.
I downloaded SciTE Text Editor but it is not that colorful as N++. Looking for something better.

Thank you.

Comment: tried gedit lately ?

Comment: @KunalSangwan Tried gedit but it's not that great. I just tried eclipse and sublime text and like them better. Thanks for the answer

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26200/recommendation-for-editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Geany" It's in Ubuntu software center

Comment: It's a good one but resembles Sublime Text for the most part. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: if you can't find anything else then install notepad++(the windiows edition) in wine works perfectly well

Comment: also have a look at bluefish and aptana studio (aptana.com)

Answer (score 1):

Gedit

http://www.sublimetext.com/3

Eclipse

Gedit is my first preference always